# Убрать " со строки в С#

Tags: c#

Хочу убрать с определенной строки символ `"`.

Допустим через `.Replacе`:

```
text.Replace(""", "");
```

Но как написать внутри `(" ")` символ `"` ? Если C# не позволяет написать и такой код выдает ошибку.

Comment: Это называется экранирование `\"`

Comment: @EvgeniyZ точно, спасибо, видел такое, но забыл, а загуглить такое не получалось правильно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так

```
text.Replace("\"", "");
```

Или так

```
text.Replace(@"""", "");
```

А если кавычки надо убрать только по краям, а не во всей строке, то вместо `Replace` можно использовать `Trim`.

```
text.Trim("\"");
```

Только нужно учесть, что тримминг откусит все кавычки с краев, а не только крайние, например в такой строке `"\"123\""` оно откусит лишнюю кавычку справа.

Поэтому при условии, что длина строки больше 1 символа и кавычки по краям точно присутствуют, то можно обрезать их так.

```
text[1..^1]
```

Comment: последний пример с `text[1..^1]` вроде работает только в C# 8 или выше 7.3, что-то типо того, нет?

Comment: @Pekor верно, но пилить фолбэки под фреймворки 5-летней давности - так себе занятие.